# Create version of site with no header/menu?

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

So what I need is a copy my website without the header or navigation menu (it will be used in a frame for another site) but using the same database. I've considered theming the pages based on parameters in the url (e.g. www.example.com/?simpleview=true) but I can't think of how to append "?simpleview=true" to the end of all the links on the page so when they click, it stays.

If there is an elegant solution to this, it would be appreciated... otherwise I will have to make do with a messy one. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was having a subdomain "simpleview.example.com". Since I was already using the built in multisite, it opens up the same structure as "www.example.com" by default and all the links still work as they are relative. I then added a CSS file that would only show up if it was the simpleview subdomain (using the `$_SERVER` variable to get the URL) and made the elements I didn't want hidden with `{display:none}`.

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it got the job done without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The regions in a site are printed in the page.tpl.php.  Every theme defines them differently but $header is often used and you can remove that from the page.tpl.php and from THEME.info to remove that region.

It is impossible to say how to remove the menu from a given site since a menu can be set to display in any part of the page.tpl.php or as a block that can be placed in any region. One options is to remove the menu items from a given menu it will no longer appear or delete the menu itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can have different themes for your normal site and your iframe version. Use the theme key module to distinguish between the two.